# Why are my menus fine in development but no on production?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0

So right now I have a web app that is targeting .NET Framework 4.0. The web server has the following installed.

**Web Server:**

[image: Web Server]

**Local Machine:**

[image: Local Machine]

So basically my menus on my site show up fine when I debug locally and appear all on one line. However, when I publish to production my web application menu's show everything on 1 line except for the last item. I am assuming this has something to do with the Framework's installed but I am not positive.

The app pool for the application is running under the 4.0 version on the web server.

**Edit**

**CSS**

```
#content-wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:830px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.menu {
    height:29px;
    background: #fff;
    width:100%;
    border-top: solid 1px #f53200;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;
    color:#000;
}

.menu a{
    font-family: AvantGarde, sans-serif;  
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:16px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    padding: 6px 13px 6px 13px;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
}


#contact ul {
    list-style:none;
    float:left; 
}

#contact ul li {
    margin:5px 0px;    
}

#contact label {
    color:#fff;
    float:left;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <a  class="home"  href="#home">HOME</a>
    <a  class="about" href="#about-us">ABOUT US</a>
    <a  class="contact" href="#contact-us">CONTACT US</a>  
</div><!--menu-->
```

Sorry just found the menu piece.

Comment: Post your code so we can see.

Comment: This could be related to a number of issues, such as environmental, versioning, css, etc.  Please show the code relating to the menu.

Comment: With the IE developer tools, make sure that the document modes match between the 2 environments.  Different modes will cause the CSS to be handled differently.  It's unlikely to be a .Net framework version problem.

Comment: @David Well I used the developer tools and tried a document mode locally, looked good. Published to the IIS server, and then tested with the same document mode and it still put it on the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow...well the real issue was that my fonts were not getting applied. I then realized that the fonts folder was not even getting published. So I added them to my .csproj and everything worked out great on the next publish.